# Is the apostrophe used properly?

Tags: apostrophe

It is for a checklist.
3.Plan website according to business' strategy.

Comment: Do **you** think the apostrophe is used properly? Why or why not?

Comment: No, because you'd pronounce it "businesses".

Comment: Could be that *business* is being used as an adjective, in which case no apostrophe is required.

Comment: @WS2. It's certainly being used as a modifier, so no apostrophe is required.(Grammarians can argue for hours about whether it's an adjective.)

Answer (score 1):

**business' strategy** and **business strategy** are subtly different.

When you say **business' strategy**, you mean *strategy of (my) business*. This may be any kind of strategy. It may not necessarily fit into the common conception of what a **business strategy** is, which is a *strategy to carry out and improve practices of business*.

By using *business* as an adjective, you're effectively averaging over all *business' strategies* and using it as a non-specific catch-all term. Using *business'* as a possessive, you're using the word much more specifically. Here I would presume the purpose of this would be to contrast your strategy to the typical business strategy.

For example,

*He asked me to show him my business strategy. I was not expecting his reaction when I showed him my business' strategy.*